# Many OpenGL drawing areas swapping buffers slowdown problem

Tags: opengl, gtk

I'm having a slowdown problem when using openGL with gtk (though gtkglext) and doing animations.

Essentially I have an application that does certain displays using OpenGL in a GTK app.  Many windows can be open at once (and certain windows can have multiple drawing areas).  So its possible to have say 20-30 openGL drawing areas on the screen at once.  None of the drawing is too heavy and openGL does that very fast.

My problem comes when all these displays are animating it really slows down the application.  After much research into the problem I have determined it is the swap buffer call to openGL that is causing my problems.  When drawing in GTK you mush do all your drawing in the widgets expose event.  So when you want to draw you call gtk_widget_queue_draw on the drawing area widget and then when GTK is processing its events it will call the expose event serially on all the widgets that need drawing.  The problem comes in when after the drawing is done, I need to call swap buffers to paint the actual openGL on the screen (Because of double-buffering).  This call seems to block (because vysnc is on) until the monitor refreshes.  This isn't a problem when there is say 3 drawing areas on the screen, but when there is a ton, there is a ton of swap buffer calls all blocking and really slowing down the app because each of these swap buffer calls are called in their own expose event and none are in sync.

My question is then is there some way to sync all the swap buffer calls so there isn't so much blocking.  Turning off vsync (Ugly in itself because its OS/openGL implementation specific) fixes the speed problem but then there is tearing issues.  I'm not sure how multi-threads will help because I have to do the swapbuffers in the GTK expose event so the drawing is in sync with GTK, unless there is something I'm not thinking of.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 20+ windows, what do you expect? Each one is vsynced to the same timing: the screen refresh. Each one will have to do a bunch of memory operations during that time. All at the same time. Of course there's going to be slowdown. Unless you have 20+ processors, they're going to have to get in line one behind the other.

Really, there's not much you can do besides limit the number of GL windows shown to the user.

Comment: Say each OpenGL window draws only one triangle. The V-Sync blocking the thread SwapBuffers was called from is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach to tackle this problem would be using a own thread for each OpenGL context to swap.

However OpenGL implementors could (and they should I say) introduce a new extension that introduces "coordinated swaps" or something like that. There are some synchronization extensions, most notably http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/OML/glx_sync_control.txt